# How to set web server log files deletion at certain interval in shared hosting?

Tags: webserver, privacy, apache-log-files

I have a site created with Drupal 8 CMS. It is hosted using shared hosting(Apache web server). I read at many places, that web server logs collect and store the IP addresses and otehr data of the visitors automatically.

How can I set a time period so all the web log files gets deleted after certain period of time? lets say 30 days, so ultimately IP addresses of the visitors also gets deleted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your shared hosting provider uses cPanel and you use cPanel to manage your website, cPanel has the function to automatically delete old log files after 30 days.

Screenshot from the "Raw Access" page of cPanel; note the "Remove the previous month's archived logs from your home directory" option:

[image: cPanel Raw Access page]

Comment: Yes, that option is there, and your answer is true. But another thing I came to know from my host. even if I delete data in cPanel after 1 month, but hosting provider keeps those data for 1 year in actual APACHE log data(Main). Hence, if I mention in my privacy policy that "Data is deleted after 30 days", it will not be true in actual sense. In this case, I can just mention "we collect data" as you mentioned in another answer. Or I as a site owner, do not have any business with that main APACHE LOG data? But again that data is from our site!

Comment: Might be they are keeping data for security, spam, DDOS Attack etc reasons. So they can trace the issue, if needed.